# Custom type to QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I have a custom struct like this:

```
struct aReminderStruct{
    QString name;
    QDate date;
    QTime time;
    QString reminderText;
};

aReminderStruct myNewReminder;
```

How can I convert `myNewReminder` to `QByteArray` once filled with data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boost serialization in Qt: is it a proper way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785814/boost-serialization-in-qt-is-it-a-proper-way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define custom datastream operators like that:

```
struct aReminderStruct{
    QString name;
    QDate date;
    QTime time;
    QString reminderText;
};

// you need this if you want to use your type with QVariant
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(aReminderStruct)

QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const aReminderStruct &a)
{
    out << name << date << time << reminderText;
    return out;
}

QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, aReminderStruct &a)
{
    in >> name >> date >> time >> reminderText;
    return in;
}
```

...

```
int main(...)
{
    QApplication app(...);

    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<aReminderStruct>("aReminderStruct");
     ...
    aReminderStruct a;
    a = ...;

    QByteArray data;
    QDataStream ds(&data, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    ds << a;
}
```